# how to nest css into a react app with tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am working on  a react project with tailwind and I want to add some custom css but i keep getting this err
'
Nested CSS was detected, but CSS nesting has not been configured correctly.
Please enable a CSS nesting plugin *before* Tailwind in your configuration. '

I followed the docs and edited my tailwind.config.js file and it didn't work

```
    export const content = [
   "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
   "./public/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
   ];
       export const theme = {
       extend: {
       colors: {
         'custom1': "#1e1e1e"
           },
       boxShadow: {
         'sm': '0 5px 5px -5px rgba(233, 88, 12, 1)'
           }
             },
                };



   export const plugins = [
    require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
     require('postcss-import'),
      require('tailwindcss'),
      require('autoprefixer'),
      ];
```

what should I do

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting), you add `tailwindcss/nesting` in your PostCSS configuration (`postcss.config.js` or equivalent), not your Tailwind configuration (emphasis mine):

> […] to use [tailwindcss/nesting] all you need to do is add it to your **PostCSS configuration**, somewhere before Tailwind:
>
> ```js
> // postcss.config.js
> module.exports = {
>   plugins: {
>     'postcss-import': {},
>     'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
>     tailwindcss: {},
>     autoprefixer: {},
>   }
> }
> ```

---

As an aside, all your other plugins seem to be PostCSS plugins, not Tailwind plugins and thus should be in your PostCSS configuration too.

Comment: you are right ,  I realize this now , but I don't see a postcss config file do i create it or it should be auto created somehow??

Comment: You should have created it when you first integrated Tailwind into your project. Otherwise, if you didn't need to and Tailwind still works, then are you using `react-scripts` from `create-react-app`? If so, you would need to `eject` the project and then modify the PostCSS configuration.

Comment: yeah i did that in the newly created app and everything seems to be working fine now thanks.